# Unexpected behaviour when running iptables from php

Tags: php, iptables, captivenetwork

I'm running the following code from within php

```
$ipAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$mac = `arp -an |grep $ipAddress | awk '{print $4}'`;
$c = "sudo iptables -t mangle -I internet 1 -m mac --mac-source $mac -j RETURN";
shell_exec($c);
```

after it, output of

```
#iptables -L -v -t mangle  

 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  215 18676            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MAC D0:17:C2:48:1E:4F
   26  1717 RETURN     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 RETURN     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
  340 26189 MARK       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MARK set 0x63
```

note that there is no RETURN in the target

If I run the same command from bash shell as sudo, the output is

```
$ sudo iptables -t mangle -I internet -m mac --mac-source D0:17:C2:48:1E:4F -j RETURN

pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MAC D0:17:C2:48:1E:4F
    0     0 RETURN     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    0     0 RETURN     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
    0     0 MARK       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            MARK set 0x63
```

Observe that there is a RETURN in the target

I have modified sudoers with visudo to enable php to run the said command as root

I also tried system(), exec and using backtick operator in php. But, all is the same.

**I could not understand why this happens and a remedy to it.**

Comment: What do you mean, `enable php to run the said command`, what user have you given access exactly? Note that if you do this from the browser, it is the web-server user you need to give access.

Comment: Yes. I gave www-data the access to sudo for that command & as I mentioned, it runs but doesn't add RETURN target. That's unexpected to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string assigned to `$mac` ends with a newline characters, thus breaking the `iptables` command. Removing the newline, for example by using `explode` instead of `awk`, should fix this:

```
$ipArp = `arp -an | grep $ipAddress`;
$mac = explode(' ', $ipArp)[3];
```

I'd like to add that this kind of script scares me a little. Blindly passing values to a shell command can have very bad consequences.  I don't think this particular script is exploitable, but giving sudo permissions to PHP is not a good idea from a security point of view.

Comment: Yes. But that's giving me the correct mac address. It runs the iptables command also. Problem is that the RETURN target is not getting added. I suppose that is something specific to php because from bash shell it works.

Comment: If you suspect permissions are to blame, then please also add the relevant line(s) of your sudoers file.

Comment: Yes. I did check var_dump($mac). It gives string(18) "D0:17:C2:48:1E:4F " Also, it's not a permission problem as the command runs. With bash and a non-sudo user, it complains.

Comment: Also, I considered security consequences. It's really scary to use php with sudo. But, as this is for use in internal network, it won't be a major issue.

Comment: Fixed and undeleted the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Good catch indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The solution :-

**I made a script /usr/bin/addtheuser and gave sudo access to www-data for this script only.**

/usr/bin/addtheuser:-

```
iptables -t mangle -i wlan0 -I internet 1 -m mac --mac-source $1 -j RETURN
```

When I tried running from php

```
$c = "sudo /usr/bin/addtheuser ".$mac;
shell_exec($c);
```

Now it worked as expected.